# Code that saves button touch for iOS app

Tags: ios, uibutton, save, boolean

I have a BOOL that's a character inside a Button.

```
-(IBAction)RED:(id)sender{

human.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"REDman.png"];

REDguy=YES;     //BOOL

if (REDguy==YES){
    Red.hidden=NO;
    Purpleguy=NO;   //BOOL

}
```

With the above code, I click on the RED button that's a custom button and in viewDidLoad. When clicking RED button, I start game and play as REDguy instead of original Purpleguy. When the game ends and I go back to viewDidLoad, the REDguy button that I clicked on didn't save. Now I have to click on REDguy button again to play with him.

How do I make it that REDman.png UIImage is saved once I press the RED button. I want even to save if I exit app and go back in, that I start off with REDguy instead of having to click REDguy?

//THE BELOW CODE DOESN'T WORK FOR SAVING A BOOL INSIDE A BUTTON

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"save"];
 REDguy= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];  //Doesn't work with or without REDguy in the front
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Comment: Is your question about how to save data/images to `NSUserDefaults` or is it about how to deal with the button press?

Comment: How to deal with saving the data only when the button is pushed.

Comment: This is confusing. Your first sentence claims you know how to save a `BOOL`. Then your last paragraph claims you can't. Which is it?

Comment: I know how to save a bool but I don't know how to save a bool that first requires a button push.

Comment: A button press is an event. As @rmaddy asks, do you know how to write an event handler? If so then save the BOOL in the event handler. If not then do some research on event handlers